# vboxusers group missing after virtualbox installation

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, user-accounts

I try to install VirtualBox in my machine. I ran `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-qt`
 from the *universe* package.

At the end of the installation the tutorial I'm following it is highly recommending to double check the groups and therefore adding the own user to the group: `sudo adduser $USER vboxusers`
Bash returns a pretty clear error: `adduser: The group 'vboxusers' does not exist.`

Since I'm not sure why the group is not created during the installation I'm wondering if I can simply just create it and add myself to it. However just wondering if this maybe indicates a deeper problem which will cause me trouble later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the group and then add yourself to it, it should cause no trouble.

Comment: hmm nice and simple. :P

Comment: The question is, why doesn't it exist? Is this a symptom of other issue?